# Stacking divs with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, ektron

I am using a CMS (Ektron), using Bootstrap as a framework.

I have access to write HTML and CSS but only within the `<div class="container">`, so I basically start off with `<div class="row">`.

I am trying to make some DIVs full width.  I can do it with:

```
.full-width-div{
height:100vh;
width:100vh;
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

But then I am having issues of the next full width div stacking on top.  I can use margin-top:800px to position the lower div and then use media queries to tediously control the positioning.

Is there a better way of doing it?  Feel free to forward me to any duplicate questions.  I can't seem to find the answer as I don't have control outside of the `<div class="container">`.

Answer (score 0):

With this being in Bootstrap, I ended up setting:

```
.container{
width:100%;
}
```

Which then just allowed me to use rows for the rest of the items.

Thanks for all your help!